# Using $window.onbeforeunload to save data then log out of firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

When a user closes or refreshes a browser I would like to save the time to a firebase database and then log them out of firebase.

I can do one or the other using `$window.onbeforeunload` but fail when I try to do both at the same time.

I can save the time by doing the following:

```
    $scope.onExit = function () {         
      userRef.update({ lastLogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });    
    };
    $window.onbeforeunload = $scope.onExit;
```

or I can log the user out (using the logout service) by:

```
    $scope.onExit = function () {         
      logOutService.logoutUser();    
    };
    $window.onbeforeunload = $scope.onExit;
```

If I combine the two only the first item works (in the example below only the time gets logged)

I have creating as separate functions and combining them but still only the first one works.

```
    $scope.onExit = function () {         
      userRef.update({ lastLogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });    
    };

    $scope.logOut = function () {         
      logOutService.logoutUser();    
    };


    $scope.combined = function () {
      $scope.logout();
      $scope.onExit();
    };

    $window.onbeforeunload = $scope.combined;
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

**Update**

Ok the above does work if I put the `$scope.onExit();` before the `$scope.logout();` (I simplified the scenario for the question). The issue happens when I put in a third function like below:

```
$scope.onExit1 = function () {
    userRef.update({ lastLoginPrevious: data.lastLogin });
};

$scope.onExit = function () {
    userRef.update({ lastLogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
};

$scope.logOut = function () {         
   logOutService.logoutUser();    
};


$scope.combined = function () {
    $scope.onExit1();
    $scope.onExit();
    $scope.logout();
};

$window.onbeforeunload = $scope.combined;
```

where the new function is moving the current `lastLogin` time against a user to the `lastLoginPrevious`. I am doing this by using a `snapshot()` to get the `data.lastlogin` value and this seems to be what is causing the issue as if I change the `data.lastlogin` to `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` it works fine with three functions. Any ideas why I cannot use a `snapshot()` in this scenario?

**Update**

OK, I got to the bottom of this. I was trying to call `data.lastlogin` from outside of the `snapshot()` therefore it wasn't working. Once i nested my functions in the `snapshot()` it all worked ok.

Comment: Is it possibly because you're calling the combined methods in the wrong order. You're calling logout before onExit, It would seem plausible that you cannot update something if you're already logged out. If not add some logging throughout your code to see where the execution gets to in the various methods.

Comment: In the project I'm did, I was unable to send GET request when I use $window.onbeforeunload, what I did was place the logic outside of the angular application, and it works. Not sure with your scenario though

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Rob I did try the update before the log out with the same result, only the time gets logged and the user does not get logged out.